# Appending a command with evaluated parameters to a macro

Tags: expansion

I'm trying to have a command `\appendtocmd` that does that:

```
\def\contents{Files:}
\def\value{yo man}
\appendcmdto{contents}{section}{\value}
```

contents contains now `"Files: \section{yo man}"`
so when I evaluate it anywhere, it will show "Files:" and create a section.
Note also that `#3` of the macro is FULLY evaluated when it is called.

I was trying to make it with `\expandafter`, `\expandnext`, `\csname`, etc., but to no avail. If you know a solution, I would also appreciate an explanation, WHY
it works :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to achieve, but here's a definition for `\appendcmdto` and `\xappendto`; the latter does complete expansion on the third argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\appendcmdto}[3]{%
  \edef#1{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{#1}%
    \space
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname #2\expandafter\endcsname
    \expandafter{\expandafter\unexpanded\expandafter{#3}}%
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xappendcmdto}[3]{%
  \protected@edef#1{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{#1}%
    \space
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname #2\expandafter\endcsname{#3}%
  }%
}
\makeatletter

\def\contents{Files:}
\def\somevalue{yo man}
\def\someothervalue{Ehi! \textbf{\somevalue}}

\appendcmdto{\contents}{section}{\somevalue}

\show\contents

\xappendcmdto{\contents}{subsection}{\someothervalue}

\show\contents

\stop
```

Running this with LaTeX will show on the terminal

```
> \contents=macro:
->Files: \section {yo man}.
l.28 \show\contents

? 
> \contents=macro:
->Files: \section {yo man} \subsection {Ehi! \protect \textbf  {yo man}}.
l.32 \show\contents

?
```

Comment: This is almost what I want! One issue though: the macro in #3 is not fully expanded as can be shown by running: `\appendcmdto{\contents}{section}{\somevalue\somevalue}`. Only the first `\somevalue` is expanded. I already fixed it myself and I'll be happy to accept your answer if you fix it (and I'm pretty sure you can do it, considering that I was able to :) ). I think that I understand why it works, but `\expandafter`s make me dizzy.

Comment: @tombuc If you want full expansion you should tell so in your question.

Comment: I added "FULLY" to the question text.

Comment: @tombuc OK, and I added the trick.

Comment: Ok, accepted, it does precisely what I want. Why did you use `\protected@edef` in the second version?

Comment: @tombuc Try the same exact code, with only `\edef` in place of `\protected@edef` and count how many errors you get. `;-)` If you're sure that full expansion can be carried over (no “dangerous” commands such as `\textbf`) then `\edef` is OK.

Comment: In my usecases it would work with `edef`, but it is more robust that way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

(don't redefine `\value` in LaTeX  but...)

```
\def\contents{Files:}
\def\value{yo man}
\def\tmp{\appendcmdto{contents}{section}}
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\value}
```

This is assuming `\appendcmdto` is defined somewhere (your question didn't make that clear)

or just

```
\makeatletter
\def\contents{Files:}
\def\value{yo man}
\def\tmp#1{\g@addto@macro\contents{\section{#1}}}
\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\value}
```